# Zoom Control Missing (+) and (-) Image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I am having problems with the zoom control for google maps. The (+) and (-) image is not showing, only an invisible link.

I think it might be the javascript code. I am attaching a picture and code snippet. Suggestions are very welcome =)

**Screen Shot Map:**

[See Image Link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/118326936@N06/12800565523/)

**Code snippet:**

```
    ...
    function initialize()
    {
        "use strict";
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var listing_lat = jQuery('#property_latitude').val();
        var listing_lon = jQuery('#property_longitude').val();

        if (listing_lat==='') {
            listing_lat=google_map_submit_vars.general_latitude
        }

        if (listing_lon === '') {
            listing_lon = google_map_submit_vars.general_longitude
        }

        console.log(listing_lat + ' / ' + listing_lon);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            scrollwheel: true,
            disableDefaultUI:false,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(listing_lat, listing_lon),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('googleMapsubmit'),
            mapOptions
        );
        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

        var point=new google.maps.LatLng(listing_lat, listing_lon);
        placeSavedMarker(point);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
    }
    ...
```

Comment: It could be something else. Using this code and setting some values for lat/lng I get map.

Comment: Looks like a css problem to me.

Comment: I found the glitch by looking at "Google Maps API V3 : weird UI display glitches", suggested by geocodezip. Now I need some help on how to make this permanent. I understand the problem is related with CSS and I need to overwrite the following style "max-width: 100%", but only for the google map image. Any suggestions on how to target this with CSS without affecting all the other images.

Comment: Below you can find a screenshot form chrome developers, http://www.flickr.com/photos/118326936@N06/12801986834 Thanks for your support!!!

Comment: I try to add these two lines of code to my Style.css, but is not making any difference. Suggestions a very welcome! =)         #map_canvas img { max-width: none; }                                #gmnoprint img { max-width: none!; }

Comment: I got it to work!!! =) Thanks again to geocodezip and Anto!!! The snippet is: .gmnoprint img { max-width: none!important; }